# How do you time consecutive events in the browser, using Javascript in an HTML script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, setinterval, thread-sleep

I have just started learning JavaScript, coming from a Java/Clojure background and I am trying to do a simple thread-sleep command that will allow me to have lines of text appear on the screen, at one second intervals. I thought about using the `setInterval` function instead, but because I am dealing with multiple functions, I thought `setTimeout` would be better. The problem I am encountering is that all of the text is printing in the browser instantaneously, as though the `setTimeout` functions weren't even there. Below is an example using the "Happy Birthday" song, which I think succinctly illustrates the problem. How can I make the program below run, line by line, at one second intervals?

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Happy Birthday</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script>
                var name = "Joe",
                    i = 0;

                while (i < 2) {
                    setTimeout(document.write("Happy Birthday to you!<br>"), 1000);
                    i ++;
                }
                setTimeout(document.write("Happy Birthday dear " + name + ",<br>"), 1000);
                setTimeout(document.write("Happy Birthday to you!<br>"), 1000);
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `seTimeout` expects a function reference as first parameter – you are not passing one, but are _calling_ a function instead, which is a fundamental difference. Besides that, you should not be using `document.write` – when it is called after the initial parsing process is done, it will _replace_ the current document completely. (Only reason you did not run into this yet, is because you handled setTimeout incorrectly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delay evaluation of some code, this code should be put into a function; that function reference should be passed into `setTimeout`. For example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.write('Hello world!');
}, 1000);
```

As it stands, you *evaluate* `document.write` expression instead immediately - that's why you see all the writings occurring simultaneously.

As a sidenote, please please please don't use `document.write` unless you're really know what're you're doing. It's quite easy to 'log' something just by adjusting `innerHTML` of `log` element. For example:

```
<div id="log"></div>
<script>
  var log = document.getElementById('log');
  setTimeout(function() {
    log.innerHTML += 'Hello world!<br />';
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Also, don't forget that each timeout is processed independently. To set up a chain of events, you'd manually increase the delay - otherwise all the functions will be called almost immediately after each other.

Overall, here's how it can be done:

```
<div id="log"></div>
<script>
var name = "Joe",
    i = 0,
    delayedMessage = function(msg) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += msg;
      }, ++i * 1000);
    };

    delayedMessage("Happy Birthday to you!<br>");
    delayedMessage("Happy Birthday to you!<br>");
    delayedMessage("Happy Birthday dear " + name + ",<br>");
    delayedMessage("Happy Birthday to you!<br>");
</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m3z9mexg/).

Comment: Wow! Adding time to timeouts executing in parallel by a factor of i was not the solution that I expected. I heard that JavaScript is single threaded; so does this mean that the browser maintains a thread-pool in some other language the background?

Comment: Think of it rather as a “delayed execution stack” – and yes, the browser maintains that as part of its JS execution environment. But this doesn’t change the single-threaded nature of JS per se – should the engine still be busy with other stuff at the time such a delayed action was to be executed, it will be further delayed until the engine is “free” again to perform it. (For more critical timers, you might want to look into `requestAnimationFrame` as well.)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you were executing the document.write and then setting the timeout handler with its return value which is clearly wrong.

Remember you must always pass a function (a handler) to every event you want to react to.

So, the correct code is:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write("Happy Birthday to you!<br>");
}, 1000);
```